# 500 Internal server error in stacksnippets.net

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Go to http://stacksnippets.net/ or click "Run code snippet" in a stack snippet.

```html
​
```

It says

> **500 - Internal server error.**
>
> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it
>   cannot be displayed.

Comment: Looks fine now.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not for me :(

Comment: Reproduced on PC with company's firewall and personal mobile connection, both on Chrome 40.

Comment: This reproduces for me as well. The snippets thing is down.

Comment: Funny. Broken for me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same problem was [asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284780/1529630) in meta.stackoverflow.com.

[Haney](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2420979/haney)♦ [answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284855/1529630) this:

> Sorry about this folks. We're doing some server upgrades this week
>   (see: [#SnowOps](http://www.twitter.com/#SnowOps) hashtag on Twitter)
>   and we're pretty sure we accidentally took down the Stack Snippet
>   server temporarily. The odd part is that, while we *had* monitoring on
>   it, nothing was fired or triggered so we didn't know it was down. It
>   *should* be back now, and you'd guess correctly if your assumption is that I'm double checking the error monitoring on it now. ;)
>
> Sorry again!

Answer (score 3):

I tried connecting with different browsers and devices in my network, and it didn't work.

Then I tried connecting to http://stacksnippets.net using a proxy, and it worked.

So I changed the public IP of my router, and it worked.

My old IP was 88.7.72.86. I hope it won't be assigned to any stackexchange user.

Comment: I have the problem again, but now changing the public IP doesn't fix it.